# Why do i have to show that a problem L $ \in $ NP before i start a polynomial reduction?

Tags: np-complete, np, decision-problem

i want to do a polynomial reduction from the Independent-Set-Problem which is NP-complete to the AUCTION-Problem, to show that AUCTION $\in$ NP-complete,
but why do i always have to show first, that our problem(in this case AUCTION) $ \in $ NP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a problem L is NP-complete if and only if:

- L is in NP
- L is NP-hard: every problem A in NP can be polynomially reduced to L.

So to show that L is NP-complete, you have to demonstrate both the properties.

Comment: Is is not right to say, if i successfully reduce a NP-complete problem L to another problem K, K has the properties of an NP-complete problem, which implicates that K is in NP and K is NP-hard?

Comment: @M.Mac This is my idea: think about unSAT; the problem is in coNP, since SAT is in NP. We can define a nondeterministic Turing Machine that solves unSAT in polynomial time, since we have a machine with the same properties that decides the complementary problem. But a problem is in NP if it has a polynomial verifier, and we don't know one for unSAT yet. In the same way, your reduction shows that K is NP-hard and that there is a NTM that solves K in polynomial time, but does K have a polynomial verifier?

Comment: @M.Mac No. By successfully reducing an NP-complete problem $L$ to another problem $K$, you've proved that $K$ is NP-hard. NP-complete means NP-hard _and in NP_. In particular, the halting problem is NP-hard but it certainly isn't in NP, so it's not NP-complete.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I see, but is NP-hard not defined as, all problems L $\in $ NP which are succesfully reduced to another problem K? Why does it not implicate that K is in NP?

Comment: @M.Mac No, that's not how NP-hard is defined. You can look that up anywhere.